# What version of ubuntu do i need for a Intel Core 2 duo laptop with 6gb ram?

Tags: intel

I have a laptop with Windows 7 Pro and a Core 2 duo processor. (Lenovo SL510 Laptop)
My Lpatop has 6Gb ram.
What version of ubuntu do i need? And will it work at all?

Answer (score 0):

Those specs will comfortably run full fat regular Ubuntu. More than man enough, though you do not mention your graphical specs which could be a weak point.

Comment: My graphics are integrated

Comment: My 7 year old  Core 2 duo laptop that was XP with 1.5GB runs the 64 bit version. I can run Firefox & several smaller apps fine, but if I load several large apps it starts to swap and gets real slow. I did change from Unity to gnome-panel or fallback with 12.04.